# Open link from one iframe in to another iframe

Tags: html, iframe, anchor

I am attempting to make a 4 section iframe page.  I have figured out how to embed a webpage in to one of the frames.  But now, I am trying to find a way to open a link into a different iframe on the same page.

For example, we have our admin section and we can click a link to view a full report.  I am attempting to have this report show up in a different iframe instead of the link sending me to a different page.  I know there are things called anchors but I am unsure how to use them.  below is the code I currently have.  Thank you ahead of time for you help.

```
<body>
<table width="547" height="397" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td><iframe height="410" width="100%" frameBorder="0" src="http://www.mypage.com" iframe name="topl_frame" id="topl_frame" target="bottoml_frame">your browser does not support IFRAMEs</iframe>   
</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><iframe height="410" width="100%" frameBorder="0" src=""     name="bottoml_frame">your browser does not support IFRAMEs</iframe></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this site is your site http://www.mypage.com ? 
if it's you can add target for each link and on click in this link open it on the another ifream

Comment: any reason you're using iFrames and not just modifying the dom directly? (see: http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Well I am a total noob at programming.  I just now picked up on a bit of PHP but have no idea how to do this.     mypage.com is not my page.  I am attempting to use an admin page in the section and it is for the company I work for so I can not let the URL out.  Is there a way to make every link in frame 1 to make it show up in frame 2?  Or is there a better way to approach this project?